# Delete call logs more than 5 days old

Tags: sms, call-history

I want to delete call logs and sms that are older than a few days. Is there any way to delete call logs and sms that are older than 5 days?

I using android 4.1.2, micromax a110q.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Call Log Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softrelay.calllog) app. This is free app. [Call Log Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wlan.calllogmaster.free) is another great free app but it will only work for call logs.

Comment: Good tools, anything for sms?

Comment: `Automatically delete incoming messages (SMS) on receiving or after specified interval` : From Call Log Monitor Google Play description :)

Answer (score 0):

You can long press and choose remove from call log. Unfortunately, you'll have to delete the entries one at a time, but it can be done. But if you want to completely [erase contacts](http://www.safewiper.com/tutorials/erase-iphone-contacts-before-selling.html) from your iPhone, you have to try professional data eraser app, due to the simple deletion can be recovered by some data recovery app.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which clearly asks for a way of doing it without deleting each entry individually.